# Compare columns in R dataframe

Tags: r

Below is the dataframe. I am trying to compare 2 columns so that I get the output I require

```
asd <- data.frame(Ratings= c(1,2), Reviews = c(45,54))
```

Output I get

```
c("1" = asd$Reviews[asd$Ratings == 1], "2" = asd$Reviews[asd$Ratings == 2])
 1  2 
45 54
```

But if I do in a reverse way, I do not the expected output

```
c(asd$Reviews[asd$Ratings == 1] = 1, asd$Reviews[asd$Ratings == 2] = 2)
```

Expected output

```
45 54
1  2
```

Comment: `setNames(asd$Ratings, asd$Reviews)` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setNames`

```
setNames(seq_along(asd$Ratings), asd$Reviews)
45 54 
 1  2
```

Or use `names<-`

```
do.call(`names<-`, asd)
45 54 
 1  2
```

which would also work in the new data

```
asd <- data.frame(Ratings= c("Yes","No"), Reviews = c(45,54))
do.call(`names<-`, asd)
   45    54 
"Yes"  "No"
```

Or the same expression used in OP's post

```
setNames(c(1, 2), c(asd$Reviews[asd$Ratings == 1], asd$Reviews[asd$Ratings == 2]))
45 54 
 1  2
```

Or more easily

```
library(tibble)
deframe(asd[2:1])
```

---

Or another option is `:=` with `dplyr::lst` and then `unlist`

```
library(dplyr)
unlist(lst(!! glue::glue("{asd$Reviews[asd$Ratings == 1]}")  := 1, 
         !! glue::glue("{asd$Reviews[asd$Ratings == 2]}")  := 2))
45 54 
 1  2
```

Comment: Hi , for this dataframe ````asd <- data.frame(Ratings= c("Yes","No"), Reviews = c(45,54))````, your code does not work

Comment: @user11740857 It gives me `deframe(asd[2:1])
   45    54 
"Yes"  "No"`.  Also, the `Ratings == 1` should be changed as well when you are changing the values